# Which words to omit?

Tags: nlp, similarity, stop-words

I'm trying to find some similarity measure between two sentences. Fot that I make use of individual semantic similarities of two words. But there are lots of words in the dictionary that I make from the sentences I have. I want to eliminate some words from the sentences that I don't think conveying information about the content. First I removed the words with fewer letters but I don't think it is reasoble because it also removes some informative words.

Look at the parts of some sentences here

```
"Despite the fact that ..."
"There's a debate such that ..."
"To sum up ..."
"Although ..., there is ..."
```

If I had a text file involving these words, I would remove them from my dictionary and let only the informative words remain there.

Is there any list of such words that you know for English so I can use to filter my dictionary?

Comment: My approach for that type of problem is to remove the head and tail of the distribution. Very common words (i.e. stopwords) add almost no information regarding similarity. Conversely, very rare words tend to  be typos. You have to be careful with the threshold for uniqueness. YMMV.

Comment: This is a very clever idea. Thanks for the comment. I think it might also work for other languages. Could you please give your comment as an answer. So, I can accept it if no other good answers arrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lists of common "stop words" available, e.g., [here](http://norm.al/2009/04/14/list-of-english-stop-words/).

Stop words may also be somewhat domain dependent.  For example, the [US Patent Full Text Database](http://www.uspto.gov/patft/help/stopword.htm) apparently considers "claim" and "embodiment" to be extremely common, which I doubt is true for non-patent-specific documents.

Comment: Actually, the keyword I was looking for is "stop words". When I search for "most frequent words", I see language classes :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: Yeah, "stop words" is not the term that would immediately spring to mind.  How would somebody who is not already familiar with the term think of that?

Answer (score 2):

One approach for that type of problem is to remove the head and tail of the distribution. Very common words (i.e. stopwords) add almost no information regarding similarity. Conversely, very rare words tend to be typos. You have to be careful with the threshold for uniqueness, and it will depend on the origin and heterogeneity of your corpus: user-generated input tends to contain many more unique typos than content from curated sources such as Wikipedia.